# Django problem with request.get to postgresql

Tags: python, django, database

Getting stuck with this issue, I've got a table that has date, category and sum and I'm trying to make a query that can choose between dates to get records, but when i pick dates it screams "column "2020-12-12" does not exist"

views.py

```
def outgoings_history(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        date_from= request.POST.get('date_from')
        date_to= request.POST.get('date_to')
        search_result = Outgoings.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')\
            .raw('SELECT suma, kategoria, date FROM outgoings WHERE date BETWEEN "2020-12-12" AND "2020-12-12"')
        return render(request, 'outgoings_history.html', {'data': search_result})
    else:
        displaydata = Outgoings.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')
        return render(request, 'outgoings_history.html', {'data': displaydata})
```

forms.py

```
class PickADate(forms.Form):
date_from= forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
date_to= forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())[enter image description here][1]
```

The date '2020-12-12' is just a example and it has records this day but still doesn't show anything

Comment: Do you use a POST request? Normally for filtering, **GET** requests are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `.raw` for this, you can use a `.filter():

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def outgoings_history(request):
    search_result = Outgoings.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
    ).order_by('-date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PickADate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            date_from = form.cleaned_data['date_from']
            date_to = form.cleaned_data['date_to']
            search_result = search_results.filter(
                date__range=(date_from, date_to)
            )
    return render(request, 'outgoings_history.html', {'data': search_result})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. Now it says ""The view accounts.views.outgoings_history didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: That is likely because you did not `return render(...)` *outside* of the `if`'s...

Comment: Do you mean with else? I didin't change it. it is the same as in my previous post

Comment: @Hudy_edd: every code path needs to return a HTTP response, it means that there is a combination of `if` and `else`s that does *not* return *anything*, hence `None`.